# How can I mirror Django logging to a second file temporarily?

Tags: python, django

I want to create task-specific log files that reflect what's happening during a particular operation, but I want these logging messages to also go to the primary Django log.

My current solution, which seems to work fine at first glance, is something like:

```
logger = getLogger("%s:%s" % (__name__, task_id))
handler = FileHandler(task_log_file)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# Work

logger.removeHandler(handler)
```

As I said, this works, but the main issue that occurs to me is that this logger isn't really temporary -- from what I've read of `logging.Manager` each logger will just hang around indefinitely until shutdown.  In this case, when I'm done I know I won't use the logger again (okay, technically I might, but that will be rare), and assuming the system is stable this could be running through hundreds of thousands of tasks.

Is there a "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a way to **mark-and-sweep** your logging resource files, or just use a **singleton** pattern.

Comment: Not sure I full understand here.  By mark-and-sweep I assume you mean a periodic log scanner -- this seems overly complicated, not to mention part of my goal is to have per-job logs available immediately.  The loggers are all singletons from what I understand; part of my issue is that I want the per-job logger to _not_ act like a singleton, but to exist just within a particular scope and get released when exiting the scope.